# Efficient way of embedding categorical features in tensorflow / keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, embedding

Is there anyway to efficiently embed a lot of categorical features? I'm making a recommender system and some user and item features are categorical. Recent blog posts suggest to embed these rather than using one-hot encoding (see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/decoded-entity-embeddings-of-categorical-variables-in-neural-networks-1d2468311635) or [here](https://medium.com/@satnalikamayank12/on-learning-embeddings-for-categorical-data-using-keras-165ff2773fc9))

However, at the moment I write my embedding layers as such:

```
item_input = Input((1,), name='item_id')
user_input = Input((1,), name='user_id')

item_embedding_layer = Embedding(num_items, latent_dim_items, name='item_embeddings', input_length=1)
user_embedding_layer = Embedding(num_users, latent_dim_users, name='user_embeddings', input_length=1)

item_emb = Flatten(name='item_flat')(item_embedding_layer(item_input))
user_emb = Flatten(name='pos_neg_user_flat')(user_embedding_layer(user_input))

all_embed = Concatenate()([item_emb, user_emb])
```

If I now add categoricals, I would have to create a new `Embedding` layer for each. That quickly gets messy. For example I have a dataframe that with item features that I believe should translate to so-many embeddings `category: embedding`

```
{'item_category_level_1': {'n_uniques': 10, 'n_latent': 4} 
 'item_category_level_2': {'n_uniques': 50, 'n_latent': 10}}
```

One way forward is to create the layers in a loop, but it does not seem a really beautiful method. Especially since I keep defining different input elements for each input. My data generator then needs to return a extremely long list.

You can also combine embeddings using a higher `input_shape`, but then the latent_dimensions are equal for each input. That is also not what I want.

I feel like I should be able to create a custom layer `EmbedAndConcat` but I'm not sure that is the best way forward. Are there some ideas on how to do this?